# Android replace fragment doesn't hide underlying fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have the following problem:

My app consists of several fragments that are dynammicly added. There is one fragment with a push button and an textedit (called 'fragA').

If I click the push button I want to show an different fragment with some text (called 'fragB'). I do this with the following code (in fragA class):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment howFragment = new HowFragment();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
            transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.flQuestion, howFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            }
        });
```

Now the problem is this:

When i push the button on fragA the fragment (fragB) is created and show on the screen but when I push on the location where the pushbutton was on fragA it makes an new fragment (fragB). Also if i push where the textedit on fragA was located it opens an keyboard on fragB..

It looks like FragB is just overlaying fragA without replacing it.

I also want to achieve that when i swype to the next fragment that fragB is removed and fragA is just showed normally (state when not pressed button)

## Update #

When trying to add and remove this is the following logcat output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090015      (com.example.eindwerkappv1:id/flQuestion) for fragment HowFragment{419c93c8 #3   id=0x7f090015}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)  
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution now.

I still use the replace method but I had to catch the ontouch event in the new fragment:

[Fragment over another fragment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue)

See previous link for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your `fragA` fragment is defined in your XML layout?

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding), this is what happens when you use the `<fragment>` tag:

> the system inserts the View returned by the fragment directly in place
>   of the  element.

This is why you cannot remove the previous fragment, as it does not exist. 
If you want to changes fragment from code, you have to add the first fragment from code too.

You need to use a container like a `FrameLayout`, and add the first fragment to this container in the `onCreate()` of your activity, using [`FragmentTransaction.add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29).

Then `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method should work.

Comment: No in my xml i just define linearlayout so no fragment tag. I add them dynamically so that can't be the problem.. I use am viewpageradapter to get the fragments on the screen

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you just call the `.remove()` on the `EditText` Fragment and `.add()` the new `TextView` `Framgent` instead on osing the `.replace()`

do some thing like this:

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(addCommentFragment)
.add(R.id.containerForFragments, commentFragment, "comment"+ 
String.valueOf(numOfComments)).commit();
```

this worked for me.

Comment: I've tried this but then the app crashes, I maybe have to say that i don't have fragments defiened in the xml layout files, I add them dynamically.
transaction.add(R.id.flQuestion, howFragment).remove((Fragment) btn.getTag()).commit;

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090015 (com.example.eindwerkappv1:id/flQuestion) for fragment HowFragment{419c93c8 #3 id=0x7f090015}

Comment: please edit your question, and paste the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: can you show you current code? is this the code you are using right now: "transaction.add(R.id.flQuestion, howFragment).remove((Fragment) btn.getTag()).commit;"?

Comment: first of all,never use Fragment as a name for a Fragment... it's a bad practice to give an object same name as the object it self and it can cause you problems. Second if Fragment fragment is already inside your flQustion (I guess it's a FrameLayout) then the remove method should come first and only after you should add the new one as I wrote in my answer... try it and tell me what is the result, and did you tried to check what is the 0x7f090015 View?

Comment: hmm, I don't use Fragment as a name. It is a typecast (Fragment) to typecast the tag from the button, the problem is that I can't get the name of the current fragment when in the onclicklistener?

Comment: you can have many fragments in a layout, but you can save your last added fragment as a global object...

Comment: but I am working inside the fragment class itself, so I just need the 'this' or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question. you are working inside a FrameLayout that is part of your Activity layout and you are removing and adding fragments.

Comment: Yes i want to show an different layout (fragment) when i push a button

Comment: Great, Man... So add the correct answer for future use... and accept it.