# After replacing a fragment with other fragment, clicking on empty places in new fragment performing operations of previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In android I am replacing my first fragment with second fragment upon some button click using the below code:

```
       public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
       @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....
       @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager
                .beginTransaction();
            fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.frag1Id,frag2);

            fragmenttransaction.commit();
            }}}
```

with the above code, on click the page is redirecting to fragment2 from fragment1 by replacing the fragment1.As my second fragment layout contains only some controls there is a lot of empty space. When, by mistake, I click on that empty space an action is performed which is related to first fragment controls. Some how the first fragment controls are present in the background. Can I please get a solution to get rid of this issue.

Comment: you should seriously put some code here.It appears to be Magic to me.

Comment: try calling `fragmenttransaction.beginTransaction()` before you replace the fragment.

Comment: @Rehana Any luck? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is a good and proper way of doing this but I did it like this: I simply set the background of the whole view in `Fragment` to a non-transparent color and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing solution from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389903/1022003 worked for me. You need to set Touch Listener to True for overlapping fragment.