# Replaced fragment still in background and clickable events responding

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I replace a `Fragment` with another Fragment, the replaced Fragment is still behind the new Fragment and the clickable events in the replaced Fragment are still working. I can't see any of the old Fragment, but the touch events are still working.

I tried even clearing the backstack before replacing but to no avail.

**Why is this happening?**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
    MatchedFragment.newInstance(matchHistoryId, matchUserId, matchAvatar), "matchedFragment").commit();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set clickable of your current layout to true

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

[Fragment over another fragment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue)

Comment: worked great! is this a bug or should I be putting the clickable for every fragment?

Comment: Great solution SteD