# why the added fragment get click event after remove

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing a strange problem. I have 4 fragments A,B,C and D. At starting I added fragment A then replace with Fragment B using `fragmentTransaction.replace(id,B)`. then I added fragment C using  `fragmentTransaction.add(id,C)`. Fragment C contains some buttons. Then I use fragmentTransaction.replace(id,D). The problem is when fragment D is visible and I tap on the possition where button lie on fragment C, the click event of button get fired.

I can't understand why it happens. If I use replace for all fragments then it is working fine. Please help me out. I need to use `fragmentTransaction.add`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can look

[Fragment over another fragment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue)

and I want to see how do you init fragment method "onCreateView".

like this?

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

But,sometimes I use fragment like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(...);

view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Because I'm so lazy.Thanks for your question so that I have to search the reason of this question.

Comment: Thank for the replay. Yes we can do this. But I just curious to know why it is happening, I mean why the added fragment get the click event even after getting replaced with other fragment.