# Previous fragment views get focus

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have activity in which added two fragments. when i am clicking on top fragment the views from previous fragment get focus. I should have the previous fragment in backstack for some other purpose. how to clear focus from previous fragment?

Comment: please share your code what you are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set clickable of your current layout to true

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

[Fragment over another fragment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue)

Comment: not helping. the focus still goes to previous fragment when app is minimised and maximised.