# Hidden fragment still receiving user input

Tags: android, android-fragments

One of the screen in an app I'm developing have multiple sub-screens implemented as fragments that are controlled by a bottom navigation bar.

This is my code for when the user wishes to switch fragments:

```
protected final void switchTab(int index) {
    if (curTabIndex == index) {
        return;
    }

    if (bottomNavigationBar.getCurrentTabPosition() != index) {
        bottomNavigationBar.selectTabAtPosition(index, true);
    }

    curTabIndex = index;
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.alpha_in, R.anim.alpha_out);

    detachCurrentFragment(ft);

    // Attempt to reattach previous fragment.
    BottomTabbedActivityFragment fragment = reattachExistingFragment(ft);

    if (fragment != null) {
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        fragment = fragments.get(curTabIndex);
        ft.add(contentContainer.getId(), fragment, (fragment.getClass().getName()));
        ft.commit();
    }

    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    curFragment = fragment;
}

/**
 * Attemps to detach any current fragment if it exists, and if none is found, returns;
 *
 * @param ft the current transaction being performed
 */
private void detachCurrentFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Attempt to detach current fragment.
    if (curFragment != null) {
        ft.hide(curFragment);
    }
}

/**
 * Will attempt to reattach a previous fragment in the FragmentManager, or return null if not able to,
 *
 * @param ft current fragment transaction
 * @return Fragment if we were able to find and reattach it
 */
@Nullable
private BottomTabbedActivityFragment reattachExistingFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragments.get(curTabIndex).getTag());

    if (fragment != null) {
        ft.show(fragment);
    }

    return (BottomTabbedActivityFragment) fragment;
}
```

Using the snippet above, I'm able to switch between fragments smoothly. However, there's one big issue with this approach: The las fragment that was added retains user input despite being hidden.

In other words, say my user went trough this change sequence:

> `Subscreen A` -> `Subscreen B` -> `Subscreen C` -> `Subscreen A`

Logically, the input will be handled by `Subscreen A` now, since `Subscreen C` is now hidden. But the reality speaks otherwise: `Subscreen C` still is the one who receive user input.

I can even see some glitches showing `Subscreen C` while attempting to scroll in `Subsreen A`.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

---

***p.s.***, Those subscreens I have right now are super expensive to reinitialise. They all have complex view hierarchy and the user is expected to switch a lot between them. I tried `attach()`/`detach()` but it became so slow in my tests.

Comment: if you dont remove/replace you´re current fragment they´re still active, if your using listeners for events you should probably cancel them (set to null or else) as long as there not visible

Comment: I don't mind them being active despite not visible. I just need them (non-visible fragments) to not handle any incoming user input. What I'm saying is I want them to be hidden using something like `View.setVisibility(GONE)` instead of just `View.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)`.

Comment: old but maybe helpful, you just need a way to prevent the clickevent from bubbeling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue

Comment: It's not bubbling at all; the last added fragment is the _only_ one receiving input… If it is bubbling then all fragment will receive input; not in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `android:clickable="true"` to the root view in fragment's layout file.

Comment: Tried your solution, no luck.

Comment: Put this line in all of three A,B, C fagment's layout.

Comment: I did put it on all of them…

Comment: It's weird. I had the same problem. And put this line make everything work great.