# Fragment overlapping one on another in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, overlap

I am fetching data in list view using fragment from MySql and here is a button on the upper side when I used to click on the button it doesn't replace the fragment it overlaps in one to another [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQQTG.png) and [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf6mm.png) clicking on button.

Here is the code where I am fetching data in list view format and on the click button i would like to open a new fragment but its overelapping.

```
public class PlayQuiz extends Fragment{

public String subject;

String myJSON;
private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";  
private static final String TAG_NAME = "subname";

String selcsub;
Button b1;

JSONArray peoples = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;
TextView ss,name;

InputStream is = null;
String res = null;
String line = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_quiz, container, false);

    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ss = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PlayQuizSubjectWise fragmentManager = new PlayQuizSubjectWise();//.beginTransaction();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.playsubjectwise, fragmentManager);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Main List xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sarvashikshan.PlayQuiz" 
android:background="#DCDCDC"
android:id="@+id/playsubjectwise">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Subject"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the list xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#DCDCDC"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PlayQuizSubjectWise XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:text="Next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Finish" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your fragment

Comment: @jigarsavaliya please check

Comment: where is the code of  `PlayQuizSubjectWise`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your *second* fragment's parent layout must have a background.

**PlayQuizSubjectWise XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"                                        //Here
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `add` use `replace`

**Replace**

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.playsubjectwise, fragmentManager);
```

with

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.playsubjectwise, fragmentManager);
```

Try this

```
PlayQuizSubjectWise fragmentManager = new PlayQuizSubjectWise();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.playsubjectwise, fragmentManager);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: can u post yout main fragment where u added

Answer (score 2):

It overlaps because you are calling `fragmentTransaction.add` which just adds the fragment to the container whilst keeping all old fragments visible.

Instead, use `fragmentTransaction.replace` which will replace all existing fragments with the new one.

Comment: The answer is correct according to the first (unedited) question you asked. If it is not helping something else is the matter. You should provide a reproducible code sample. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Add background color to your fragment and make fragment clickable

```
android:background="fff"
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: `R.id.playsubjectwise` check what is playsubjectwise it should be framelayout

Comment: please check it above i have added all the xml file

Comment: which is your fragment xml out of those two

Comment: The first XML i posted initials are **Main List xml file**

Comment: check my updated answer this will solve your problem

Comment: add this two lines in fragment xml

Comment: Sorry brother..it's not working same problem :( or I guess there is something silly I am doing

Comment: no it should work. make sure that you added this lines in fragment
check this meanwhile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `replace` for fragment, your layout `playsubjectwise` shouldn't include any view.

You should pick up the `TextView, ListView and Button` to a new fragment, then you can use `replace` to toggle two fragment.

MainList xml, just a layout, dont include any view

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sarvashikshan.PlayQuiz" 
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    android:id="@+id/playsubjectwise">

</RelativeLayout>
```

then put those view to a new fragment as TempFragment.

for the start, you execute `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.playsubjectwise, TempFragment);`

if you want replace to `fragmentManager`, execute
`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.playsubjectwise, fragmentManager);`

it's fake code, hope you can understand.

Comment: didn't understand properly..because if I use same thing in another then whats the meaning i want some another data another view

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced this problem of overlapping of fragments.

> For the solution:
>
> Just give the Background Color to the parent layout in all
>   fragments using XML.

For eg.

**this is onefragment.xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:background="#fff"**
    android:orientation="vertical">
       <!-- Fragments UI Components-->
</LinearLayout>
```

**So here i have given background color #fff(White color). so like this you should give background color in all fragments**

I Hope it will help you :)

Comment: this is a band aid. it will just hide the existing fragments and does nothing to explain why they are there in the first place. Much better to fix a problem than hide it.