# How to hide the home fragment when I'm in the 2nd fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have the home fragment who is composed of : a title, a button, a list. When I click on the list I display a 2nd fragment where you have all the detail of the clicked element. The title and the list of the home fragment disappear but the button stay there. I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389620/fragment-over-another-fragment-issue)  that I could set on the 2nd fragment clickable = true to avoid the click triggers of the home fragment but that didn't work and I find that way of working kind of not reliable.

I don't know what is the trick but here is my `home_fragment.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_apero"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        ... />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_apero"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then with my java code I display the new fragment :

```java
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        //------------------------------------- Add a event ---------------------------------
        Button btn_add_apero = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_apero);
        btn_add_apero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final View inflater = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setView(inflater);
                builder.setTitle("Super un nouvel apéro !");

                final EditText name_apero = (EditText)inflater.findViewById(R.id.edit_apero);
                final EditText date_apero = (EditText)inflater.findViewById(R.id.edit_date);
                // Add action buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.text_add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        LaperoDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(root.getContext(),
                                LaperoDatabase.class, "lapero_db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

                        AperoDao dbApero = db.getAperoDao();
                        Apero new_apero = new Apero(name_apero.getText().toString(), date_apero.getText().toString());
                        dbApero.insert(new_apero);
                        AperoIncomingAdapter a = (AperoIncomingAdapter) ((ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_apero)).getAdapter();
                        a.addApero(new_apero);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.text_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        //------------------------------------- the incoming list -----------------
        ArrayList<Apero> incomingApero = new ArrayList<Apero>();
        initList(incomingApero, getContext());
        AperoIncomingAdapter adapterIncomingApero = new AperoIncomingAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.apero_coming_cell_layout, incomingApero);
        final ListView listIncomingApero = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_apero);
        listIncomingApero.setAdapter(adapterIncomingApero);
        listIncomingApero.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                Apero selectedItem = (Apero) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Fragment newFragment = new AperoDetailFragment(selectedItem);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

The issue should be there I think because I don't see any other way that the button would be in the `AperoDetailFragment`

Comment: You shouldn't be using FragmentTransaction at all if you're using Navigation and a NavHostFragment. You should [navigate](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) to your new Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like I was replacing the wrong fragment in this part of the code :

```java
//------------------------------------- the incoming list -----------------
        ArrayList<Apero> incomingApero = new ArrayList<Apero>();
        initList(incomingApero, getContext());
        AperoIncomingAdapter adapterIncomingApero = new AperoIncomingAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.apero_coming_cell_layout, incomingApero);
        final ListView listIncomingApero = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_apero);
        listIncomingApero.setAdapter(adapterIncomingApero);
        listIncomingApero.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                Apero selectedItem = (Apero) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Fragment newFragment = new AperoDetailFragment(selectedItem);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

where instead of `transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,newFragment);` I should have coded `transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,newFragment);` which solved the issue